# The forgetful Shomer

Tags: time, eating, memory, trust-neemanut

With regards to some of the mitzvos(shema,sefirah,Chanukah lighting) one cannot sit down to a set meal until he completes the mitzvah once a certain time comes (30 min before shekiah or tzeis -its a machlokes). However, if one appoints someone(a shomer) to remind them to complete the mitzvah then eating would be permitted even before doing the miztvah.

My question is ,if one appoints someone who proves to be forgetful can we continue using such a shomer. Does it make a difference if the shomer forgets 1 time or 3 times(chazaka),or it doesnt make a difference and one can continue using this shomer?

Comment: Regardless of the halachic status, "The Forgetful Shomer" would be a great title for a collection of short stories